# Reprint a table in js terminal without a waterfall print or clearing console

Tags: node.js, terminal

JS has this great feature called console.table. It allows a list of objects to be displayed as a table.

Now I could like to create a simple little program that continously displays the same table just with updated values (individual values change very fast, so a re render only on change isn't an option)

So far I got the best results simply rendering one table after the other, which leaves the most recent table always at the bottom. The problem with this is that it fills the entire terminal extremely fast and as such makes scrolling back up difficult.

Another option would be to clear the terminal and the print the table again. But this leads to excessive "blinking" which makes the table unreadable.

So basically I would need a way to print the console.table, somehow get the terminal cursor back to the start of a table and the overwrite it, similar to how it works in a lot of terminal programms like htop. Is there a way to do this in node js?